# iPhone 7 black Current/vibrations when charging

Tags: iphone

Has any one had and issue of feeling electric current through back of phone when charging. It's like vibrations. I have tried different cables, plugs and charged in different locations and the same every time.

Answer (score 1):

This is so commonly misunderstood that I shall attempt to provide a short précis, then link to a good explanation which is not overly-technical.

**Common misconception - earthing/grounding**

Most small household appliances are not, in fact, earthed at all - even if there is a valid earth pin on the mains plug.
They are what is known as **'double insulated'** & carry this logo

[image]

The 'transformers' on this type of equipment are not the same as in high-power equipment & don't use a step-down coil transformer, linear supply. Instead they use a switch-mode supply.
All PSUs, whether linear or switch-mode leak a small amount of current due to capacitance. In double-insulated devices there is no true ground/earth so the design is optimised to try to prevent this leakage.
Unfortunately, switch-mode supplies run at very high frequencies, so the smaller capacitance in the smaller transformer ends up leaking just as much as the larger capacitance in a larger transformer running at 50 or at 60Hz for example.

The leakage current is usually less than 1mA and is often as low as 10uA, but even at such low current, it can still be present and still can cause problems.

So - the tingle or buzz that you feel is in fact **you** becoming the temporary ground/earth for this circuit.
It is usually safe, & any reputable manufacturer will ensure their PSUs are well within tolerance.

Cheap copies are cheap because they don't bother with most of the safety circuitry… you know, the stuff that makes the expensive one expensive in the first place ;-)

Have look at http://www.unitechelectronics.com/sparks.htm for a much more detailed explanation. Though it is aimed at hi-fi users & deals in 240v mains, the basic principles are identical.

[copied from [my own answer](https://superuser.com/questions/932260/does-bad-electrical-grounding-mess-up-a-laptop/932411#932411) on Super User]

Comment: This is quite a good answer, but not technically correct. Double Insulation means, as it implies, 2 independent layers of insulation. Double Insulation can apply to both conventional linear/transformer supplies, as well as switch-mode. Not all PSU leak due to capacitance; it is common for PSU requiring high isolation (e.g. medical appliances) to include a capacitative shield between windings, although this requires an earthed supply.

Comment: I'm not sure how that makes it wrong.. these things are all switch mode Class II devices, which technically ought to be double-insulated - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II - rather than earthed.