# Why does my finger buzz when I slowly move it near the trackpad?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've noticed that when I drag my finger around the trackpad (not actually on the trackpad) that I get a strange little vibration. Is the haptic engine responsible for this? and why does it do it?

Comment: It's what the manufacturers would call "within acceptable parameters" & is no cause for concern. It's leakage from capacitative 'smoothers' within the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this vibration sensation is due to the MacBook being plugged in. From personal experience my 2008 MacBook Pro does this when plugged in (Official Charger) and my 2012 MacBook Pro only does this when plugged into the college power (Official Charger) so cant say for sure as I don't have your specific MacBook but am confident this may be the answer.

As you stated with the haptic feed back this could be the answer as there could be a software bug causing the vibration to be stuck on but I can't help thinking this may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is your charger not being grounded. You probably use the snap-on with only neutral and +, while the bundled cable also connects ground wire. For me this sensation occurs not only near the touchpad but anywhere on the metal surface of the laptop, even magsafe plug itself.

If you disconnect it from charging or use the bundled cable it will stop doing that.

Comment: **No. Wrong.** Basic miscomprehension of how power supplies work. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256101/85275 for a brief guide, with comprehensive links.

Comment: I actually had this happen and this is exactly what stopped it from happening. But please, do tell how is it wrong. The metal knob [in this picture](http://i.imgur.com/RbpLVkJ.jpg) is the ground. It is not connected to anything if you use the little snap-on, but it is on the cable.

Comment: The earth pin is not connected to anything, On a UK plug it must be there as that's what makes the live & neutral sockets uncover; no earth pin, no entry. If you look at what the snap-on plug connects to, you'll see it only has 2 pins.

Comment: Perhaps it is moot if your house doesn't have ground in sockets etc.

Comment: In the UK, it is illegal to not have every socket earthed. There are no plugs available that can connect to non-earthed sockets, other than those weird 'shaver-plugs' that hotels seems to have. [And please don't call earth "ground". That's a terrible US term which totally fails to differentiate between "true earth" & "signal ground".]

Comment: I should also clarify that I changed to the cable not because of this sensation - which is quite nice - but because touching another computer and this mac was very unpleasant for my wrists. Both issues went away.  [This](http://i.imgur.com/Bs3iLzC.jpg) image shows the cable version with earth connected and [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/rwlSMJZ.jpg) shows that while it has earth pin on the outside, it is simply not connected to the metal knob from charger.

Comment: Image 1 is new to me. If it implies a coil rather than switch-mode transformer I would be more than surprised. You'd need to take the power supply apart to be certain.